# How to prepare for delayed debugging of Android app

Tags: android, debugging

I have an app with service running in the background, and this service freezes or crashes (I don't know yet) from time to time.

The problem is when it happens it happens like this:

- I run my app on the run
- at some point service crashes/freezes
- half an hour later I notice this
- 6 hours after freeze/crash I have access to computer

So the problem is that typical "use the logcat" of course works but the period I am interested in is long gone.

So how to prepare for this? Can I perform something like logcat snapshot from Android smartphone (i.e. without using external computer)? Are there any other means that helps in not-live, delayed debugging session?

**Smartphone:** Samsung Galaxy Ace 2, Gingerbread 2.3.

**Details:** I don't know if the service crashed or froze, because at this point I cannot tell the difference. The service in theory should constantly send a message to the main activity, so when I see no updates I know the service do not send them, but I don't know the cause (for now).

Comment: This library might help you https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/CrashReporter

Comment: Instead of using logcat, you could use a text file to save the information. It would not contain any crashes, but it would have the last steps of your execution before the crash. I used this method when one of the apps I worked on was tested by someone in a different city and the app run for a few hours in a single session.